# Swift unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to filter the rows, when I click on some letter it's returning this

```
unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard)
```

Here is my List Data Class:

```
//
//  HomeTableViewController.swift
//  
//
//  Created by Wesley Mota on 06/06/16.
//
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {
var ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

var nome: String!
var items = [GroceryItem]()
var sobrenome: String!
var filteredItems = [GroceryItem]()


var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil

@IBOutlet weak var questionTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref.child("Cadastro").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        var newItems = [GroceryItem]()

        for item in snapshot.children {

            let groceryItem = GroceryItem(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newItems.append(groceryItem)
        }

        self.items = newItems
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    //return items.count

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView){
        return self.filteredItems.count
    } else{
        return items.count
    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    let groceryItem = items[indexPath.row]
    var items1: GroceryItem

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView) {
        items1 = self.filteredItems[indexPath.row]

    } else {
        items1 = self.items[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.nameLbl.text = groceryItem.nome
    cell.lastNameLbl.text = groceryItem.sobrenome

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    var items1: GroceryItem
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView) {
        items1 = self.filteredItems[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        items1 = self.items[indexPath.row]
    }

    print(items1.nome)

}

func filterContetnForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {

    self.filteredItems = self.items.filter({ (friend: GroceryItem) -> Bool in
        var categoryMatch = (scope == "All")
        var stringMatch = friend.nome.rangeOfString(searchText)

        return categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil)
    })

}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String?) -> Bool

{
    self.filterContetnForSearchText(searchString!, scope: "All")
    return true

}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool

{

    self.filterContetnForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text!, scope: "All")
    return true

}
}
```

Here is my CustomTableViewCell

```
//
//  Labels.swift
//  enquetepr
//
//  Created by Wesley Mota on 06/06/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 WesleyMota. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameLbl: UILabel!

}
```

Class connection with firebase database:

```
//
//  SubmitConnection.swift
//  enquetepr
//
//  Created by Wesley Mota on 06/05/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 WesleyMota. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import Firebase

struct GroceryItem {

var data: NSData = NSData()

let key: String!
let nome: String!
let sobrenome: String!
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

// Initialize from arbitrary data
init(nome: String, key: String = "", sobrenome: String) {
    self.key = key
    self.nome = nome
    self.sobrenome = sobrenome
    self.ref = nil
}

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    nome = snapshot.value!["nome"] as! String!
    sobrenome = snapshot.value!["sobrenome"] as! String!
    ref = snapshot.ref
}

func toAnyObject() -> AnyObject {
    return [
        "nome": nome,
        "sobrenome": sobrenome,
    ]
}
```

}

When I click on some letter >> [Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2trSrMuYTn4Si1RaUgxU3hLVVE/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the Story Board cell id >> [Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2trSrMuYTn4eFZITmZhcEJTS2s/view?usp=sharing)

I'm using firebase, to store data. It's working (loading) fine, but when I try to filter is happening this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i'm not sure how you configured your search controller but if you have initialized the controller with another controller, you must register programmatically your cell every time the results VC appears on the screen.

```
init(searchResultsController searchResultsController: UIViewController?)
```

That is true if searchResultsController != nil

You can register the cell in the following method:

```
func willPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController)
```

Comment: Hi @mcanto Thanks. I'm new with swift, so I don't know exactly where put this code. I'm sharing this project on the GitHub to people understand better. >> https://github.com/appseven/filterProject

Comment: OK, i just review your code and find out the problem, you are using a SearchDisplayController ( deprecated at this moment ), the main reason for the "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell" message is the fact SearchDisplayController uses it's own UITableView, not the one you registered in the Storyboard with your custom cell so for fix the issue you need to create a xib file with your custom cell and register the cell everytime the UITableView from the SearchDisplayController will be displayed. I have fixed your code, if you want i can share with you the fix.

Comment: Hi @mcanto, thanks! Share this code please, I'll see the deferences and update the source fixed on the GitHub to help other people with same problem. And share the link here! One more time, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There's a few things that could have happened, but first go to your storyboard and click on the cell that defines your 'CustomTableViewCell'.

Ensure the class of the cell is set to 'CustomTableViewCell'.
[Set the class of a custom UITableViewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EECUL.png)

Then ensure your you cell identifier is set here:
[Set a cell identifyer in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8nbX.png)

Now we need to register the cell. This is specifically what the debugger is complaining about.

In your viewDidLoad method of HomeTableViewController add the following code to register the class with the identifier.

```
    tableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Comment: @Damnien Bell, I I did exactly what you said. Now when load the view, the error is: **unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** (image) >> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2trSrMuYTn4c2hQd0R0REJvcEE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The class of the cell is 'CustomTableViewCell' (image) >> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2trSrMuYTn4SnpoX0MxQ2pMVTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @Damien Bell, Im sharing the source on the GitHub to us. >> https://github.com/appseven/filterProject

Comment: This solution also working with "Basic" table view cells. for also register basic view cell put this code `tableView.register(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this , It's working for me ,

Check below scenarios for this error ,

-Could you set the Table Cell identifier to "Cell" in your storyboard?, If yes then just add one line of code in **viewDidLoad()**

```
 self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

OR

```
self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.classForKeyedArchiver(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Make sure same identifier "Cell" is also copied at your storyboard's UITableViewCell.

Hope So it's will work for some .

Answer (score 0):

As @Damien Bell said, another thing can make this happened is you are make more than one outlet or action with single UIComponent, find and delete it if needed.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! But the labels are with one outlet: (image) >> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2trSrMuYTn4THNPN3d4QnFpSW8/view?usp=sharing